# Why does command prompt import differ from sublime text import?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pip, sys.path

I have installed with pip several packages (numpy/pandas/blpapi/pyarrow). I work with a Windows 64-bit machine, python3.6 in a sublime environment.
While all packages are shown as correctly imported in the command prompt, some packages are not found by my sublime scripts.

To try and remedy this problem, I used sys.path.insert and changed the names of my scripts, to no avail. The traceback below describes what I'm seeing:

Code in Command Prompt:

```py
>>> import pyarrow
>>> import pandas
>>>
```

Code in Sublime (better_name.py):

```py
print('Hi')
import numpy
import pandas
```

Output of better_name.py:

```py
Hi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Documents\better_name.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pandas
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Obtaining the paths in Command Prompt:

```py
>>> import os
>>> import numpy
>>> path = os.path.dirname(numpy.__file__)
>>> print(path)
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy
>>> import pandas
>>> path = os.path.dirname(pandas.__file__)
>>> print(path)
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas
```

Trying to use sys.path.insert :

```py
print('Hi')
import sys
import numpy
import os 

sys.path.insert(1, r"C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas")
```

Output:

```py
C:\Users\Documents>better_name.py
Hi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Documents\better_name.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pandas
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

I get the same results whether I change the argument in sys.path.insert to 0.

Comment: Are you running your sublime script in a virtual environment? Are there multiple versions of python installed?

Comment: No sublime script is not run in a virtual environment.

Comment: I've installed python3.7.4 (32-bit) first then python3.6.2 (64-bit) as pyarrow requires a 64-bit python. python -V returns Python 3.6.2.

Comment: In your sublime script - try doing this `import sys` and `print(sys.version)` - this will give you an idea whether your sublime script is running the 32 bit version or the 64 bit one.

Comment: Spot on.  3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] is what I get. So my sublime is in 32 bit and my python in 64-bit. Does that mean I need to install a new version of sublime?

Comment: You can run your script from the windows command line as `C:\path\to\python-64\python.exe your_script.py` - that should work. This link has information on how to set the `default python` on your windows machine - https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that your `default` version of python points to the `32-bit version` - i.e. when you say `python` your windows system executes the 32 bit version.

One workaround is to specify the full path of your `64 bit version` - i.e. launch your script as

```
C:\PATH\TO\64-BIT-VERSION\PYTHON.EXE your_script.py
```

from the command line.

The other option is to set your windows environment variables to point to the `64 bit version` by default. This [link](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) should help

Comment: Problem solved.  I couldn't launch my script as you suggested because Python3.7 was downloaded in an area protected by administrator privileges. I simply deleted Python3.7. I now have a fully functioning BLOOMBERG-LINEDATA-PYTHON pipeline. Thank you so much!